# Did the Third Doctor ever salute the Brigadier?

Tags: doctor-who

In the finale of Series 8, Brigadier Alistair Lethbridge-Stewart's daughter Kate mentions that it had always been her father's wish that the Doctor would return his salute. Towards the end of the episode,

> a Cyberman, presumably reanimated from the Brigadier's corpse, receives said salute from the twelfth Doctor.

The modern Doctor's disdain for salutes is well known. What surprises me, however, is that the third doctor, who had the most extensive relationship with the Brigadier, never returned a salute. While the Doctor was always disdainful of military customs, he was always polite as well.

Unfortunately, it's been a long time since I've seen the Pertwee era stuff. But for those who obsess, is there any off-handed return of a salute just to be polite from Pertwee or any of the other earlier Doctors?

Comment: He saluted a Dalek; http://40.media.tumblr.com/b1c4a897d2e4c5113c926f9d0a8170ff/tumblr_ml073ah6UW1s7amo1o1_1280.jpg

Comment: I love the visible plywood in that shot.

Answer (score 3):

No I dont recall Pertwee or Baker ever saluting the Brigader, the doctor on this era often made sarcastic remarks about the military mind, (present them with a problem and they blow it up, etc). But even though they had a somewhat strained relation they realized they needed each other.

Comment: It's funny how, when you really get down to it, the Doctor can be just as bigoted and small-minded as everyone around him.

Comment: One thing that got my attention recently is that when the Doctor is sarcastic he may be doing this because (1) he's actually fond of that person and (2) he may be trying to provoke him/her into a reaction to overcome a limitation. This from rewatching the interactions between 10 and Mickey. So, yes, he has quite a lot of prejudices, but from his POV they, and his remarks, are at least partially justified. When he doesn't care he doesn't even bother to address that person.

Comment: @confusedwhovian As in ["Under the Lake"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-3.html) when he tells Pritchard "It's OK, I understand: you're an idiot." and then doesn't bother to talk to him again.